# bm and siunitx mismatch

Tags: siunitx, bm

With this mwe,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,siunitx}

% change nothing to the problem
\sisetup{
    detect-weight,
    detect-display-math
}

\begin{document}
$\bm{\num{.1}}$
\end{document}
```

I get this error message

```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                A sequence was misused.
l.11 $0<\bm{\num{.1}}
                   $
```

With this other mwe :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,bm}

\sisetup{
    detect-weight,
    detect-display-math,
    detect-inline-weight=math
}

\begin{document}
$\num{5}x\bm{5x\num{5}}$
\end{document}
```

I have the next error message :

```
! Argument of \__tl_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.11 $\num{5}x\bm{5x\num{5}}
                      $
```

And `\mathbf` doesn't work and makes uggly "x".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,bm}

\sisetup{
    detect-weight,
    detect-display-math,
    detect-inline-weight=math
}

\begin{document}
$\num{5}x\mathbf{5x\num{5}}$

$\bm{0.1}\quad\mathbf{\num{.1}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why don't you write either `\textbf{\num{.1}}`?

Comment: I follow the advice given to use `\bm` with success until now. Nevertheless, `\mathbf` doesn't work as you can see on my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can protect the `\num` and `\SI` commands with braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,siunitx}

\begin{document}


\sisetup{detect-weight = true,detect-inline-weight = math}

$\num{5} \SI{50}{\km}$

$\bm{bob{\num{5}\SI{30}{\km}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]