# bm and siunitx transparent use

Tags: siunitx, bm

I try to have `bm` and `siunitx` packages transparent use based on this answer: [bm and siunitx mismatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416289/bm-and-siunitx-mismatch)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,siunitx}

\newif\ifbm
\bmfalse

% New bm
\let\Oldbm\bm
\renewcommand{\bm}[1]{%
    \bmtrue\Oldbm{#1}\bmfalse}

% New num
\let\Oldnum\num
\renewcommand{\num}[2][]{%
    \ifbm\Oldbm[math-rm=\mathbf,#1]{#2}%
    \else\Oldbm{#2}%
    \fi}

% New SI
\let\OldSI\SI
\renewcommand{\SI}[2][]{%
    \ifbm\OldSI[
            math-rm=\mathbf,
            number-unit-product={\mbox{\bfseries\,}},#1
            ]{#2}%
    \else\OldSI{#2}%
    \fi}

\begin{document}

$\bm{bob\num{5}\SI{30}{\km}}$
\end{document}
```

But I have this error message :

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
\reserved@d 
l.25 $\bm{bob\num{5}}
                   $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are errors in your code. E.g. you are using `\Oldbm` instead of `\Oldnum` in the `\num` definition. And `\SI` has three arguments not two.

A working code would be the following. Be aware that as both commands have optional arguments and so are fragile they need to be protected by a brace. So imho you don't gain much compared to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416405/2388

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm,siunitx}

\newif\ifbm
\bmfalse

% New bm
\let\Oldbm\bm
\renewcommand{\bm}[1]{%
    \bmtrue\Oldbm{#1}\bmfalse}

% New num
\let\Oldnum\num
\renewcommand{\num}[2][]{%
    \ifbm {\Oldnum[math-rm=\mathbf,#1]{#2}}%
    \else  \Oldnum[#1]{#2}%
    \fi}

% New SI
\let\OldSI\SI
\renewcommand{\SI}[3][]{%
    \ifbm{\OldSI[
            math-rm=\mathbf,
            number-unit-product={\mbox{\bfseries\,}},#1
            ]{#2}{#3}}%
    \else\OldSI[#1]{#2}{#3}%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
\num{5} \SI{30}{\km}

$\bm{bob}$

$\bm{{\num{5}}}$

$\bm{bob{\num{5}\SI{30}{\km}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for the corrections. But the 2 arguments new `\SI` command is based on egreg's 2 arguments answer. I agree with you, your protected solution is better than creating new commands. I accept your both answers.

Comment: Well sometimes it works if you use less arguments, the commands can pick them up from the following stream. But I added braces (not quite sure if they are really needed) to protect the command and then this will fails.