# \bm and \num inside align

Tags: siunitx, bm

What I'm trying to do is write a number as `\num{number}` in boldface inside an `align` environment. After looking for an answer, I found [bm and siunitx mismatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416289/bm-and-siunitx-mismatch), but it didn't solve the problem. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, bm}

\usepackage{siunitx}
  \sisetup{detect-weight = true,detect-inline-weight = math} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416289/bm-and-siunitx-mismatch

\begin{document}

$\bm{bob{\num{5}\SI{30}{\km}}}$ % example looked

  \begin{align*}
      \bm{P_{i,\text{\textbf{ef.}}}} &= 139.40 \times 87.47 \bm{\approx 12193.88} \text{ \textbf{kN}} \\
      \bm{P_{0}} &= \num{12193.88} \times (1 - 0.15) \bm{\approx {\num{10364.79}}} \text{ \textbf{kN}}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which generates the following

[image]

In the second equation the implementation of `\bm{\num{10364.79}}` doesn't make the number bold. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It should be `\SI{12193.88}{\kilo\newton}` rather than `\num{12193.88}\text{ kN}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `detect-display-math = true` to the `\sisetup` command:

```
\sisetup{
    detect-weight = true,
    detect-inline-weight = math,
    detect-display-math = true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much =)